# nhibernate 3.2 how to turn off show_sql

Tags: nhibernate

I am using nhibernate 3.2, I dont know by default show_sql is turned on or off, but decided to turn it off in my configuration anyway.

I dont know how to turn show_sql off, but I have following 2 lines in my configuration file.  are they the same?

db.LogFormattedSql = false;

db.LogSqlInConsole = false;

```
    public static Configuration Initialize()
    {
        var configuration = new Configuration();

        configuration
            .Proxy(p => p.ProxyFactoryFactory<DefaultProxyFactoryFactory>())
            .DataBaseIntegration(db =>
            {
                db.ConnectionStringName = "test";
                db.Dialect<MySQLDialect>();
                db.KeywordsAutoImport = Hbm2DDLKeyWords.AutoQuote;
                db.LogFormattedSql = false;
                db.LogSqlInConsole = false;
            })
            .AddAssembly(typeof(User).Assembly)
            .CurrentSessionContext<LazySessionContext>();

        var mapper = new ConventionModelMapper();
        mapper.WithConventions(configuration);

        return configuration;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`LogSqlInConsole` enables or disables SQL console logging.

`LogFormattedSql` enables or disables *formatting* of that SQL.

Comment: thank you, I guess they are not the same thing, how do i disable show_sql in my configuration?

Comment: `LogSqlInConsole = false` should do, but that's the default anyway. If you are seeing all the SQL in the console, someone else is turning it on (or there's a log4net configuration that blindly shows everything)

Comment: Where are this configuration options located?

Comment: @DiegoMijelshon, sorry, forgot to tell. I'm using fluent for registrations, and haven't found location of this properties.

Comment: @Johnny_D use the `ExposeConfiguration` method in your `FluentConfiguration`. This gives you access to NHibernate's native Configuration, on which you can use the above. It might also be possible to do this with Fluent's methods; I really don't know. One of the reasons I don't use or like Fluent is that it needlessly wraps and renames native functionality (this was a bit more useful some versions ago)

Comment: Pity, but haven't found them even though ExposeConfiguration.

Comment: Once you have ExposeConfiguration, it's right there. You get a Configuration instance; you can just use the code above.